# How to read a final string value in ASM?

Tags: java, scala, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Suppose someone gives me Java bytecode of the following source:

```
class MyClass {
  public static void foo() {
     final String bar = "Hello";         
  }
}
```

I want to scan all methods in this class `MyClass`.
If any method contains a `final` `String` variable called `bar`, I need to outputs the literal value of the variable. In this case, `Hello`.

I managed to get to the variable called `bar` in the method as follows:

```
// Scala code
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.objectweb.asm._
import org.objectweb.asm.tree._

def processClass(is:java.io.InputStream) = {
  val cn = new ClassNode
  val cr = new ClassReader(is)
  cr.accept(cn, 0)
  is.close
  val methods = cn.methods.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[MethodNode]]
  val m = methods(0)  // get first method as an example
  val vars = m.localVariables.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[LocalVariableNode]];
  val bar = vars.find(_.name == "bar").find(v => Type.getType(v.desc) == Type.getType(classOf[String])) 
  if (bar.isDefined) {
         // how to read value of final variable "bar"?
         // also how to check for final?
  }
}
```

However, I am not able to figure out how to extract the literal `"Hello"`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your Java example does not compile. If the `foo` is method, then it should be `foo()`. If the `foo` is class, then `void` should be replaced with `class`. Please clarify.

Comment: @TagirValeev My mistake. Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot check for `final`, because for local variables it's not stored in the classfile at all, thus ASM cannot extract it. You can only check whether the variable was assigned once or more, looking for `astore*` bytecode instructions. However even final variable can be assigned in bytecode several times. For example, this is the valid Java code:

```
public static void foo(boolean flag) {
    final String bar;
    if (flag)
        bar = "Hello";
    else
        bar = "Goodbye";
}
```

What do you want to print in this case?

Also the assignment can be a result of expression like this:

```
public static void foo(String name) {
    final String bar = "Hello "+name;
}
```

What do you want to print in this case?

It's hard to help you without knowing exactly what are you trying to achieve. Assuming you want to track the simple assignments of strings to the variables, you should visit the method bytecode and look for the sequences like `ldc #x/astore*`. From ldc parameter #x you [can understand](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLdcInsn%28java.lang.Object%29) which constant is loaded. From astore opcode or parameter you [can understand](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitVarInsn%28int,%20int%29) which variable slot you are saving the result to. After that you should consult the local varaible table (which you already know how to do) to know which variable name this slot corresponds in given code position (note that variable slot may be reused for different variables).

If you really need to track the `final` keyword on local variables, you have to parse source Java file instead. There are ready convenient parsers, for example, in Eclipse JDT.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tagir Valeev for the insight. I wanted the first astore instruction. This code does what I want:

Taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173813/243233)

```
// Scala code
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.objectweb.asm._
import org.objectweb.asm.tree._
import org.objectweb.asm.util.Textifier
import org.objectweb.asm.util.TraceMethodVisitor

def processClass(is:java.io.InputStream) = {
  val cn = new ClassNode
  val cr = new ClassReader(is)
  cr.accept(cn, 0)
  is.close
  val methods = cn.methods.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[MethodNode]]
  val m = methods(0)  // get first method as an example
  val vars = m.localVariables.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[LocalVariableNode]];
  val bar = vars.find(_.name == "bar").find(v => Type.getType(v.desc) == Type.getType(classOf[String])) 
  if (bar.isDefined) {
        val str = insnToString(bar.get.start.getPrevious.getPrevious).trim
        println("found text: "+(if (str.startsWith("LDC")) str.substring(5).init else "None")) // prints Hello
  }
  def insnToString(insn:AbstractInsnNode) = {
    val printer = new Textifier;
    val mp = new TraceMethodVisitor(printer); 
    insn.accept(mp);
    val sw = new StringWriter;
    printer.print(new PrintWriter(sw));
    printer.getText.clear;
    sw.toString;          
  }
}
```